# Shareware in Ubuntu repositories? (RAR)

Tags: official-repositories

I thought that all applications in Ubuntu repositories are free, but today I wanted to install rar package and its description says, that this is shareware and I could use it (without registration) only 40 days.

Are there more packages like rar? How can I find the licence of programs in repositories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of Ubuntu is [free software](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy) (meaning not just that you don't have to pay for it, but also that you can distribute it, study its source, and modify it).

However Ubuntu also includes a small amount of non-free software, in separate [components](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu): `restricted` (non-free, supported) and `multiverse` (non-free, not supported). These are programs that may be distributed over the Internet at no charge, but have restrictions that make them non-free. A prime example is [drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedDrivers) for devices which do not have fully-featured free drivers.

You can tell a package is non-free because it's from the `restricted` or `multiverse` repository. In Synaptic, check the “Section” in the ”Common” tab of the package properties. Exactly what restrictions are on the package has to be determined on a case-by-case basis. Most can be used and redistributed by anyone, but modifications are not allowed and the source code may not be available. A few, such as `rar`, have restrictions even on use. Once the package is installed, you can always find its license in `/usr/share/doc/$packagename/copyright`. On [`packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), check the “Copyright File” link in the right-hand column.

Answer (score 2):

The [rar package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/rar) is from the multiverse repository, which contains:

> Software that is not free. ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu))

If you wish to use only free software, only use the Main and Universe repositories. (And if you want 100% pure free, use a [distribution from this list](http://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html))

The licence of any installed package can be found at `/usr/share/doc/#{package}/copyright`, so /usr/share/doc/rar/copyright for `rar`. You can also find a copy of the copyright file by following the link at the right of the package page. [Here is the direct link for the rar copyright file](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/multiverse/r/rar/rar_3.9.3-1/rar.copyright).

The 40 day thing doesn't mean that it will automatically uninstall but the licence says you need to buy a licence when you have used it for 40 days. I'd just ignore this.

Even better than potentially doing something illegal - don'tmake rar archives. There really is no reason to. If you wan't a cross platform format supported almost everywhere out of the box, use zip.

Answer (score 1):

Hello **josef**,

Generally speaking you use the program *unrar* to extract RARS. A free version exists (*unrar-free*) but it has some limitations.

Note that *unrar* is *non-free* because it contains proprietary code, not because you have to pay for it.

I believe you're using the **Ubuntu Software Center**, you might find the *unrar* program by searching *unarchiver*. If you don't find anything, use the **Synaptic Package Manager** (System -> Administration).

But the quickest way to install it would be to open a terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```