# Compress and split files in the file explorer

Tags: nautilus, compression, archive, split

If you right click a file in Nautilus and select Compress, then you get a dialog where you can choose a compression format and a filename. If you click on Advanced, then there are settings to split and compress the file, but it's deactivated/insensitive. How come and how do I activate those features?

Edit: In an answer below, it has been suggested that it has something to do with rar. But I have that installed, and I don't get the options to split.

Comment: Where is 'compress' did they remove that feature?

Comment: No. Right above Properties.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only some archiving tools support splitting. One of them is RAR -- package `rar` (but it's shareware and you need to buy it after 40 days -- [Shareware in Ubuntu repositories? (RAR)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19438/shareware-in-ubuntu-repositories-rar)) and another is for example 7zip -- package `p7zip-full`. You need to install one of them (I suggest 7zip because it's completely free).

You can also create a sigle archive and then split it into parts using `split` command (or [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) for GUI).

Comment: when I installed p7zip, then I could split the file if I choose 7z. If I install p7zip-full, then I can also password protect it. So, in that regard, my question is sort of solved. But I still can't select rar.

Comment: And do you have package `rar` installed? Packages `unrar` and `unrar-free` are only for RAR decompress support.

Comment: As for multiple `zip` files ,   **7-Zip** in Wine/Playonlinux seems the easiest way  (as I failed trying the `zip` command for the given purpose, as indicated [here](https://www.lifewire.com/practical-examples-of-the-zip-command-2201158); such command, if successful, could be then added to the file-manger's context menu). Creating a big zip and then using `hjsplit` to split that, as indicated above, is a way to go (the resulting zip files can be extracted directly as the original unarchived file), but splitting an archive  seems a much slower  procedure than  direct multi-file archiving.

Comment: Looking into `zip` files in this context, it seems that the `zip` command can be used to create multiple-volume zip archives,  only that the results are not very useful,  as the multi-file zip archive cannot be extracted directly, but needs to be composed as one file  through a second command  before extraction: more [here](https://serverfault.com/a/760341/256174) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393171/32012).  Creating one archive and then splitting it with `split` is preferable.

Answer (score 8):

To activate the split option, select .rar from the file extension drop-down box.

[image]

Comment: I can't select rar, even though I have unrar installed.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad you must install rar first: apt-get install rar. Hope this late comment can help others.

Comment: Selecting `7z` also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing rar by unrar-free or the other wise around.

This can be done by simply

```
sudo apt-get install rar unrar-free
```

Comment: This doesn't let you create rar files...only extract them.

Comment: As said in a comment by  Fernando Kosh , `rar` is also needed; `sudo apt-get install rar`.  Selecting `7z` also  worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Considering the specific case of multi-segment **ZIP** files,

this is a complementary answer to the [main one](https://askubuntu.com/a/57771/47206).

As already stated in the main answer, only some archiving tools support splitting, and the main GUI doesn't seem able to create multi-segment archives in `zip` format. Alternative formats can be used though, namely `rar` and `7z`.

Also, only some tools can extract from multi-segment-zip-files, such as the ones discussed here: on that, see the end-note to this answer.

As the question specifically addresses the issue of handling archiving **from the context menu of the file manager**, I looked into some commands that could achieve the given purpose even for `zip` files: such commands, if successful, could then be easily added to the file manager as context menu entries.

Considering the `zip` tool, multi-segment archives can be created directly with a command like `zip my_archive.zip -r <file> -s 20971519` (more details under [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393163/32012)), but these are not at all useful because they are not ready to be extracted (need a supplementary `zip -s 0` command to create a large 1-file extractable archive - as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/760341/256174)) and this limitation cannot be avoided. Sending a such multi-segment archive to somebody that doesn't know this is pointless.

**As already suggested in the main answer, another way is to zip the file and then split the one-file archive with `split`** (or the `hjsplit` GUI). (I have tested the GUI and I found it extremely slow, while for the context-menu purpose the GUI is not needed.)

The idea is to add to the context menu of the file manager an entry that, with just one click, would

1. compress selected files as a single `zip` file,
2. split the zip-file  in parts of specified maximum size, and
3. remove it in order to keep only the multi-file archive.

So, I have tested with Thunar and a custom action with these three commands connected by `&&`:

```
zip -j my_archive.zip %F && split -b 20m my_archive.zip split.zip && rm my_archive.zip
```

(That is to be applied to one or more selected files, but not to directories; to apply to directories, the `zip -r` option is needed:

```
 zip -r -j my_archive.zip %F && split -b 20m my_archive.zip split.zip && rm my_archive.zip
```

)

- `-j` stands for an option for `zip` to "junk the path": unlike a terminal command containing the full path of the to-be-archived file(s) , a context menu command that uses `%F` for selected files would add to the archive a folder-in-folder structure unless `-j` is used; (source: [create zip - ignore directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710141/create-zip-ignore-directory-structure));
- `my_archive.zip` is the custom name of the not-yet-split archive; the `split` command will be applied to it and then the former will be removed with `rm`
- `%F` can be used in a Thunar custom action in order to **compress multiple files** as `zip`; alternatively, `%f` is to be used for selection of just one file;
- `-b 20m` stands for the size of the separate archive parts created by `split` as indicated [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm);
- `split.zip` is a specification that is not needed; it is the custom name of the final multi-file archive, it 
  would give something like `split.zipaa, split.zipab, split.zipac...`, and without it the output will be named `x` followed by the `aa` fragment-suffixes: `xaa, xab, xac...`, etc; there is a `split` option `-d` to use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic, but that gives an error (because apparently the extractor expects a standard ZIP multi-segment archive when it sees a numeric suffix - as suggested in a private chat by [Stephen Kitt](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/140200/stephen-kitt);
- `rm` applied to the `my_archive.zip` file will only leave us with the desired multi-segment archive.

---

### Note:

In order for the resulting multi-zip-archive to be extracted, ***a tool that supports `aa` segmentetd archives is needed***, like `file-roller` in Linux and 7-Zip in Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Using p7zip-full, as Vojtech Trefny suggested, works, but didn't enable me to choose rar as compression method. Neither did unrar. However, installing the package "rar" does present that option, and if you open Advanced, all options are sensitive.